Proof about function subset of another
i hope this question does not sound stupid.
Studying functions i encountered a problem that made me think i'm missing some fundamental thing about proof:
let $\mathcal{f}:A\rightarrow B$ be a function and $\mathcal{g} \subseteq \mathcal{f}$, prove that it exists a $A_1 \subseteq A$ such that $\mathcal{g}:A_1 \rightarrow B$.
The problem i have with this exercise is that to me it seems obvious so i'm either wrong in thinking it's intuitively right or i'm missing the reason mathematicians write proofs. Assuming we know the definition of restrinction of a function, if $\mathcal{g} \subseteq \mathcal{f}$ (every element of $\mathcal{g}$ is also an element of $\mathcal{f}$), i already know that $\mathcal{g}$ is a restrinction of $\mathcal{f}$ on some subset of $A$ (that we can call $A_1$), so what do i have to prove?
I did not add what are the definitions i'm working with, my bad.
These are the definitions i learned:
A function $\mathcal{f}: A \rightarrow B$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$ such that $\forall{a}\in{A}(\exists!b\in{B}|(a, b)\in \mathcal{f})$. 
Relation: a subset of a cartisian product.
From this definition, $\mathcal{g} \subseteq \mathcal{f}$ is just saying that every element of the relation $\mathcal{g}$ is also an element of $\mathcal{f}$. This mean to me that there is no way that $\mathcal{g}$ is not a function: being $\mathcal{f}$ just a subset of $A \times B$ with the property stated in the definition i gave, there is no way that there are elements in $\mathcal{g}$ that violates that property, since those elements are also in $\mathcal{f}$.
Also, if $\mathcal{g} \subseteq \mathcal{f}$, obviously the domain of $\mathcal{g}$ is a subset of the domain of $\mathcal{f}$.

So to me it seems this exercise is less about proving and more about formalizing, unlsess i don't really know the goal of proofs.
Edit: 
Despite @Martin answering this using a definition i did not know of function, i tried to write my proof using the definitions i learned. It still doesn't convince me to be honest but i tried thinking about this for the last few days and this is what i came up with:
Definitions:
A function $\mathcal{f}: A \rightarrow B$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$ such that $\forall{a}\in{A}(\exists!b\in{B}|(a, b)\in \mathcal{f})$. 
Relation: a subset of a cartisian product.
Givens:
$\mathcal{f}$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ 
$\mathcal{g} \subseteq \mathcal{f}$
Goal:
Prove it exists a subset $A_1$ such that $\mathcal{g}$ is a function $\mathcal{g}: A_1 \rightarrow B$
Proof:
To prove this we can assume a subset $A_1$ exists (we can always construct a subset of a set) and prove $\mathcal{g}$  is a function from $A_1$ to $B$.
Let $A_1 \subseteq A$ 
Let $a$ be an arbitrary element of $A_1$, $A_1 \subseteq A$ so
$a \in A$
Since $\mathcal{f}: A \rightarrow B$ is a function, $\exists! b \in B ((a, b) \in \mathcal{f})$
$(a, b) \in \mathcal{f}$ and $\mathcal{g} \subseteq \mathcal{f}$, so $(a,b) \in \mathcal{g}$
Since $a$ was an arbitrary element of $A_1$, $\forall a \in A_1(\exists! b \in B | (a,b) \in \mathcal{g})$ so, by definition, $\mathcal{g}$ is a function $\mathcal{g}: A_1 \rightarrow B$.
Is this proof correct?

What does it mean to say that $g\subseteq f$?  If I had to guess, I'd guess that it meant that $g$ was the restriction of $f$ to some subset of the domain of $f$, but that's just a guess.

Proofs begin with clear definitions, there is no alternative to that.  In my guess, saying one function was a subset of another would mean (by definition) that one function was the restriction of the other to a subset of the domain, so there would be nothing to prove here.  You'd just be restating the definition.  Now, perhaps you have a different definition of $g\subseteq f$ in which case you would need to prove that the other definition implied (or was equivalent to) my guess.  But without that other definition there's nothing to be said.

@lulu $\mathcal{g} \subseteq \mathcal{f}$ should mean that every element in $\mathcal{g}$ is also an element  of $\mathcal{f}$, so, if i'm not wrong, is basically either the same as $\mathcal{f}$ or a restriction of $\mathcal{f}$.

Pleasse add that to your post.  But, as you say, if that's the definition then there is nothing to prove.  The desired claim is a part of the definition (just a part, since it misses the bit where, on the subset $A_1$, we must have $g(a)=f(a)$.

@TankutBeygu  I would say that question was very different, since it specifies that the domain of $g$ equals the domain of $f$.  In the question here, we don't have that (and it is clearly contemplated that $g$ might only be defined on the subset $A_1$).

Functions are defined as sets of ordered pairs (in ZFC), hence the subset relation is defined. This is what is meant here.

@TankutBeygu that's a different question.

Sometimes, with math like this, it can feel like "there is nothing to prove." But, still, you can prove things You should: (a) make sure you have your definitions of function and subset clearly; (b) write down what $A_1$ is in exact terms; and (c) show that $g$ is a function from $A_1$ to $B$. I know it can feel like you are proving something that is obvious, but sometimes you do that in math classes in order to practice proof techniques.

In set theory based on ZFC, a function is usually defined as a set of ordered pairs such that
$$(a,b),(a,b') \in f \implies b=b'$$
holds. The domain is then defined as $\mathrm{dom}(f) := \{a : \exists b. \, (a,b) \in f\}$. See also Asaf's answer here.
We also say that $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ if $A$ is the domain of $f$ and $f \subseteq A \times B$.
Now if $g$ is a subset of $f$, then the function property also holds for $g$ and $\mathrm{dom}(g) \subseteq \mathrm{dom}(f)$. The proof is straightforward from the definitions.

 Let $(a,b),(a,b') \in g$. Then also $(a,b),(a,b') \in f$. Hence, $b=b'$. This proves that $g$ is a function. For the second claim, let $a$ be in the domain of $g$. This means there is some $b$ such that $(a,b) \in g$. Hence, $(a,b) \in f$, and therefore $a$ is in the domain of $f$.

Finally, if $f : A \to B$ and $g \subseteq f$, then also $g \subseteq f \subseteq A \times B$, and from the above $g : A' \to B$ is a function where $A' \subseteq A$ is its domain
When $(a,b) \in f$, we write $b=f(a)$, using that $b$ is unique because of the definition of a function. Then $g \subseteq f$ immediately implies $g(a)=f(a)$ whenever $a$ is in the domain of $g$. So we see that $g$ is a restriction of $f$ in the usual sense.

As an aside, according to this definition of a function, if a set $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, and $B$ is a subset of $C$, then $f$ is also a function from $A$ to $C$. This means that to a set theorist, it does not make sense to speak of the "codomain" of a function. We can talk about a function being surjective onto a set, but just saying a function is surjective without any further qualification does not make sense. This is in contrast to most areas of mathematics, especially algebra, where we do want functions to have codomains, and so we have to modify the definition.

If we want functions to have codomains (and we still want to use material set theory as our foundation), then we can define a function to be an ordered triple, consisting of a domain, codomain, and set of ordered pairs. I go into more detail about this here.

Would it be wrong to say: let $a \in \mathcal{g}$, since $\mathcal{g} \subseteq \mathcal{f}$ and $\mathcal{f}$ is a function, $\exists! b \in B((a, b) \in \mathcal{f})$. Since $a \in \mathcal{g}$ and $a$ was arbitrary, $\mathcal{g}$ is a function?

i made an error: $a \in dom(\mathcal{g})$, not $a \in \mathcal{g}$
